# Are there issues with locking a field while changing it's property?

Tags: c#, locking

```
private Foo _Bar;

public Foo Bar
{
  get { return _Bar; }
  set { _Bar = value; }
}

void LockAndReset()
{
   lock(_Bar)
   {
     // Some logic.
     Bar = new Foo();
   }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with how the lock is being used here despite the property setting `_Bar` field while in the lock? Is there any benefit to using a lock object instead of directly locking the field?

Comment: It's generally not good practice to do this, better to use another object for locking.

Comment: `lock(this)` is generally very convenient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are problems:

Thread 1 comes in with `_Bar = BarA`

```
void LockAndReset()
{
   lock(_Bar)
   {
     Bar = new Foo();
   }
}
```

Thread 2 comes in with `_Bar = BarA`. Thread 2 is blocked until thread 1 completes.

Thread 1 sets `Bar = new Foo();` (`_Bar = BarB`)

Now, Thread 3 comes in *after* Thread 1 executes `Bar = new Foo();`. It's now locking on `BarB`.

This means that thread 2 and thread 3 can *both* be executing within the lock at the same time, as they've grabbed different objects to lock on.